# Как перезагрузить одну страницу, находясь на другой?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть две открытых страницы одного сайта.
Как перезагрузить одну страницу, находясь на другой при помощи JS(JQuery) или PHP при клике пользователя?
А также, как перезагрузить определенный блок на одной странице, находясь на другой, при клике пользователя?

Comment: "Как задать вопрос и получить за это побольше минусов."

Comment: @Igor manual смотри вверху

Comment: еще можно использовать событие "storage"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В случае если страницы еще не существует то ее ни как не обновить.
А если у пользователя например открыто 2 страницы одного сайта, то можно на действия пользователя обновить 2 страницу которая открыта в другой вкладке с помощью технологии push and pull.
По стандарту сайт и браузер пользователя общается через http т.е клиент (браузер) делает запрос на сайт, там php генерирует страницу и возвращает пользователю, и без запроса пользователя сервер (php) не может отправить пользователю данные, так вот технология push может отправлять пользователю данные так как пользователь при первом заходе разрешает серверу отправлять ему данные без запросов на сторону сервера, и далее сервер может слать все что угодно на сайт. Таким образом пользователь на странице 1 сделал действия они отправились на сервер сервер принял данные и сделал push во все вкладки сайта ну и получается что вторая вкладка обновиться автоматичеки через js а данные пришлет сервер т.е работа уже не по http а через вебсокет прочитать можно [тут](https://habr.com/post/331462/)

Ну еще можно сделать ajax каждую минута на сервер и если есть изменения то забирать их и менять страницу т.е у пользователя на каждой вкладке будет посылаться ajax каждую минуту и обновляться данные если надо.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос задан не совсем понятно. Но предположу, что имеется ввиду необходимость перегрузить открытую пользователем страницу (часть контента) без участия пользователя.
Для этого можно использовать websockets